# VIM: Display Hex Code Inline

Tags: vim

I would like to have hex codes been displayed inline, no matter what filetype is activated in the current session.

So far I've found something existent and suitable for my needs: https://github.com/skammer/vim-css-color/blob/master/after/syntax/css.vim

I tried to recode the syntax file to effect all types of code, but didn't get it in the end. To be honest, I've just no clue about coding for vim. Could anyone help? I would be really glad if someone could... =/

Comment: Ehm, no I dont want to edit in hex mode. I would like to have color previews of the hex color values in an edited file. Just to have an overview of choosen colors, f.i. in a vim theme file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the alternative [colorizer - Highlight #rrggbb or #rgb color](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3567) plugin from Christian Brabandt. It works for all filetypes, not just CSS.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. I didn't find that... =D